I want to implement sensor fusion using the ekf code, not utilizing the package of ros2. (encoder odometry, ekf fusion using IMU data)
Thank you for your interest in my writing.
Currently I’m using ros2 foxy, and I’m building a raspberry pi 4 (ubuntu 20.04) environment.
I’m trying to implement ekf using data from odometry and imu (CMP10a; similar products from “wit-motion”) issued from the encoder of the motor, not using the package (eg, localization) of ros2. I don’t know the ekf in detail, so I’ve tried to implement the code by referring to multiple sites, but it doesn’t seem to work properly.
My robot is an object moving in a two-dimensional plane, and the purpose of using ekf is to implement it because I want to correct slipping or wrong rotation.
I think it would be good to use the values of x, y, yaw in odometry and the values of acceleration x, acceleration y, yaw in IMU. If you don't think it's right, I'd appreciate it if you could select the elements to use for the proper ekf.
Is there anyone who can help?
The ekf_node.py code was implemented by referring to the contents of this url("Extended Kalman filtering for IMU and Encoder")
*ros2 topic echo /imu/data_raw
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1721799092
    nanosec: 345986151
  frame_id: imu_link
orientation:
  x: 0.0005186428849981324
  y: -0.0008204675601905222
  z: -0.010593421966266087
  w: 0.9999434170259761
orientation_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
angular_velocity:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
linear_acceleration:
  x: -0.00017290115356445314
  y: -3.0374526977539064e-05
  z: 0.00478048324584961
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
---

*info log
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.18°, Yaw: 13.06°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.05°, Pitch: 0.02°, Yaw: -0.34°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.26°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 13.02°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.05°, Pitch: -0.00°, Yaw: -1.27°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.09°, Pitch: -0.01°, Yaw: -1.41°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.95°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.93°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.91°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.12°, Pitch: 0.00°, Yaw: -1.19°
[data_report_node-7] [INFO]: Lidar data or Imu data is not available yet
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.87°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.11°, Pitch: -0.01°, Yaw: -1.19°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.83°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.10°, Pitch: -0.01°, Yaw: -1.21°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.79°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.10°, Pitch: -0.02°, Yaw: -1.20°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.75°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.73°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.10°, Pitch: -0.02°, Yaw: -1.20°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.68°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.66°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.10°, Pitch: -0.03°, Yaw: -1.20°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.62°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.60°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.58°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.09°, Pitch: -0.03°, Yaw: -1.20°
[data_report_node-7] [INFO]: Lidar data or Imu data is not available yet
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.54°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.09°, Pitch: -0.04°, Yaw: -1.20°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.50°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.48°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.09°, Pitch: -0.04°, Yaw: -1.21°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.44°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.08°, Pitch: -0.05°, Yaw: -1.21°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.41°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.39°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.37°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.08°, Pitch: -0.05°, Yaw: -1.21°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.33°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.31°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original IMU - Roll: 0.08°, Pitch: -0.06°, Yaw: -1.21°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[data_report_node-7] [INFO]: Lidar data or Imu data is not available yet
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.27°)
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Original Odometry - x: 0.007, y: 0.004, yaw: -1.32°
[ekf_node-5] [INFO]: Corrected Odometry - Position: (0.004, 0.002, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: 0.17°, Pitch: -0.17°, Yaw: 12.25°)


*ekf_node.py
import os
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
import transforms3d.euler

def quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw) -> Quaternion:
    q = transforms3d.euler.euler2quat(roll, pitch, yaw)
    quaternion = Quaternion()
    quaternion.x = q[1]
    quaternion.y = q[2]
    quaternion.z = q[3]
    quaternion.w = q[0]
    return quaternion

def euler_from_quaternion(quaternion):
    euler = transforms3d.euler.quat2euler([quaternion.w, quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z])
    return euler

def radians_to_degrees(radians):
    return radians * (180.0 / np.pi)

class EKFNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('ekf_node')

        self.get_logger().info('Initializing EKF node')

        # Load parameters from YAML
        self.declare_parameters(
            namespace='',
            parameters=[
                ('frequency', 65.0),
                ('sensor_timeout', 0.1),
                ('two_d_mode', True),
                ('publish_tf', True),
                ('map_frame', 'map'),
                ('odom_frame', 'odom'),
                ('base_link_frame', 'base_link'),
                ('world_frame', 'odom'),
                ('odom0', '/odom'),
                ('imu0', '/imu/data_raw')
            ]
        )

        # Subscribe to odometry and IMU data
        self.odom_sub = self.create_subscription(Odometry, self.get_parameter('odom0').get_parameter_value().string_value, self.odom_callback, 10)
        self.imu_sub = self.create_subscription(Imu, self.get_parameter('imu0').get_parameter_value().string_value, self.imu_callback, 10)

        # Publish filtered odometry data
        self.ekf_odom_pub = self.create_publisher(Odometry, 'odom/filtered', 10)

        # Initialize state vector: [x, y, roll, pitch, yaw]
        self.mu = np.zeros(5)
        # Initialize state covariance matrix
        self.Sigma = np.eye(5)

        # Process noise covariance matrix
        self.R = np.diag([0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01])**2
        # Odometry observation noise covariance matrix
        self.Q_odom = np.diag([0.05, 0.05, 0.01])**2
        # IMU observation noise covariance matrix
        self.Q_imu = np.diag([0.01, 0.01, 0.01])**2

        self.initialized = False

        self.get_logger().info('EKF node initialized')

    # Prediction Step
    def predict(self, u, dt):
        # Extract each element of the state vector
        theta = self.mu[4]

        # Calculate state transition matrix G
        G = np.array([
            [1, 0, 0, 0, -u[0] * np.sin(theta) * dt],
            [0, 1, 0, 0, u[0] * np.cos(theta) * dt],
            [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])

        # Predict state vector
        self.mu[0] += u[0] * np.cos(theta) * dt
        self.mu[1] += u[0] * np.sin(theta) * dt
        self.mu[4] += u[1] * dt

        # Predict state covariance matrix
        self.Sigma = G @ self.Sigma @ G.T + self.R

    # Update Step
    def update(self, z, H, Q):
        # Calculate Kalman gain
        K = self.Sigma @ H.T @ np.linalg.inv(H @ self.Sigma @ H.T + Q)
        # Update state vector
        self.mu = self.mu + K @ (z - H @ self.mu)
        # Update state covariance matrix
        self.Sigma = (np.eye(len(self.mu)) - K @ H) @ self.Sigma

    # Odometry callback function
    def odom_callback(self, msg):
        if not self.initialized:
            return

        # Calculate period
        dt = 1.0 / self.get_parameter('frequency').get_parameter_value().double_value

        # Extract x, y, yaw from odometry
        x = float(msg.pose.pose.position.x)
        y = float(msg.pose.pose.position.y)
        yaw = euler_from_quaternion(msg.pose.pose.orientation)[2]

        # Log original odometry data
        self.get_logger().info(f"Original Odometry - x: {x:.3f}, y: {y:.3f}, yaw: {radians_to_degrees(yaw):.2f}°")

        # Construct measurement vector z
        z_odom = np.array([x, y, yaw])

        # Construct odometry observation matrix H
        H_odom = np.zeros((3, 5))
        H_odom[0, 0] = 1
        H_odom[1, 1] = 1
        H_odom[2, 4] = 1

        # Perform update step
        self.update(z_odom, H_odom, self.Q_odom)

        # Publish corrected odometry
        self.publish_corrected_odometry()

    # IMU callback function
    def imu_callback(self, msg):
        if not self.initialized:
            self.mu[4] = euler_from_quaternion(msg.orientation)[2]
            self.initialized = True
            return

        # Extract roll, pitch, yaw from IMU
        roll, pitch, yaw = euler_from_quaternion(msg.orientation)

        # Log original IMU data
        self.get_logger().info(f"Original IMU - Roll: {radians_to_degrees(roll):.2f}°, Pitch: {radians_to_degrees(pitch)::.2f}°, Yaw: {radians_to_degrees(yaw):.2f}°")

        # Calculate period
        dt = 1.0 / self.get_parameter('frequency').get_parameter_value().double_value

        # Construct measurement vector z
        z_imu = np.array([roll, pitch, yaw])

        # Construct IMU observation matrix H
        H_imu = np.zeros((3, 5))
        H_imu[0, 2] = 1
        H_imu[1, 3] = 1
        H_imu[2, 4] = 1

        # Perform update step
        self.update(z_imu, H_imu, self.Q_imu)

    # Publish corrected odometry function
    def publish_corrected_odometry(self):
        odom_msg = Odometry()
        odom_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        odom_msg.header.frame_id = self.get_parameter('odom_frame').get_parameter_value().string_value
        odom_msg.child_frame_id = self.get_parameter('base_link_frame').get_parameter_value().string_value
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.x = float(self.mu[0])
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.y = float(self.mu[1])
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0

        roll, pitch, yaw = float(self.mu[2]), float(self.mu[3]), float(self.mu[4])
        quaternion = quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)
        
        odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation = quaternion
        self.ekf_odom_pub.publish(odom_msg)

        self.get_logger().info(f'Corrected Odometry - Position: ({self.mu[0]:.3f}, {self.mu[1]:.3f}, 0.0), Orientation: (Roll: {radians_to_degrees(roll):.2f}°, Pitch: {radians_to_degrees(pitch):.2f}°, Yaw: {radians_to_degrees(yaw):.2f}°)')

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    try:
        ekf_node = EKFNode()
        rclpy.spin(ekf_node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ekf_node.get_logger().info('Keyboard Interrupt (Ctrl+C) detected. Exiting...')
    finally:
        ekf_node.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


